# Google Maps - Can't see full screen icon

Tags: google-maps

http://www.topozone.com/washington/pierce-wa/park/mount-rainier-national-park/

We just enabled the "fullscreenControl"  option. The link is clickable in the upper right corner but you cannot see the icon.

We do use a custom Topographic image overlay. I have tried disabling those and the issue still persists.

The code for the icon is all there, but the CSS styling for the icon image just messes up the display and not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this

```
max-width: 100%;
```

From

```
#main section img
```

On the file 'style.css' line 172